# How to display blocks on PlantUML diagram vertically?

Tags: vertical-alignment, plantuml

I've got the following sample code (in real I've got hundred/thousands of lines):

```
@startuml
[326976]<->[7bfe53]
[868224]<->[49e442]
[777408]<->[0de431]
[777408]<->[d8d3ed]
[454080]<->[99b073]
[750848]<->[05624c]
[319104]<->[264b51]
[319104]<->[ad0add]
[035840]<->[76d4fe]
[561280]<->[e7fd29]
[576640]<->[388451]
[674816]<->[bafca1]
[674816]<->[ec9992]
[505344]<->[1069ba]
[173120]<->[4ded8e]
[741888]<->[018d22]
[166464]<->[695028]
[122176]<->[5ed43a]
[122176]<->[72fcb1]
[950848]<->[93c4a2]
@enduml
```

However the diagram looks like:

[image]

With more number of blocks, the image (PNG) gets cut off with the following warnings:

> Width too large 11516268
>
> Creating image 4096x129

---

I'd like to display diagram vertically ideally with minimal code changes, is it possible?

My goal is to see shared connections on the graph when ID on the left shares multiple IDs on the right (and other way round).

Comment: Looks like you would like to have something in graphviz terms a `subgraph` I don't know if something like this is possible. A (not nice) possibility is to use `newpage` resulting in a number of pages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are looking for: `left to right direction`.

```
@startuml
left to right direction
[326976]<->[7bfe53]
[868224]<->[49e442]
[777408]<->[0de431]
[777408]<->[d8d3ed]
[454080]<->[99b073]
[750848]<->[05624c]
[319104]<->[264b51]
[319104]<->[ad0add]
[035840]<->[76d4fe]
[561280]<->[e7fd29]
[576640]<->[388451]
[674816]<->[bafca1]
[674816]<->[ec9992]
[505344]<->[1069ba]
[173120]<->[4ded8e]
[741888]<->[018d22]
[166464]<->[695028]
[122176]<->[5ed43a]
[122176]<->[72fcb1]
[950848]<->[93c4a2]
@enduml
```

[output with left-to-right-direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iixg3.png)

Additionally you might want to add double dashes.

```
@startuml
left to right direction
[326976]<-->[7bfe53]
[868224]<-->[49e442]
[777408]<-->[0de431]
[777408]<-->[d8d3ed]
[454080]<-->[99b073]
[750848]<-->[05624c]
[319104]<-->[264b51]
[319104]<-->[ad0add]
[035840]<-->[76d4fe]
[561280]<-->[e7fd29]
[576640]<-->[388451]
[674816]<-->[bafca1]
[674816]<-->[ec9992]
[505344]<-->[1069ba]
[173120]<-->[4ded8e]
[741888]<-->[018d22]
[166464]<-->[695028]
[122176]<-->[5ed43a]
[122176]<-->[72fcb1]
[950848]<-->[93c4a2]
@enduml
```

[output with double dashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4GEN.png)